# Update Column Calculations When Row is Removed

Tags: jquery, html

When I click the checkbox to remove a table row, I want my calculations to update the Totals. I've done this in similar situations by simply adding the calculate sum function to the remove row event, but I can't seem to get it to work in this situation. The code:

```
//Remove Table Row
$(document).on('click', 'input.removeItem', function(){ 
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
calculateSum();
calculateTotal();
});

// Sum Amt Collected    
$(document).on('keyup', 'input.amtcollected', calculateSum);
function calculateSum() {
var sum = 0;
var currentTable = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
$('#' + currentTable + ' input.amtcollected').each(function() {
//add only if the value is number
if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
    sum += parseFloat(this.value);
}
});
//.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
$('#' + currentTable + ' input.sumamtcollected').val(sum.toFixed(2));
}

// Daily Collection Total
$(document).on('keyup', 'input.amtcollected', calculateTotal);
function calculateTotal() {
var sum = 0;
$('input.sumamtcollected').each(function() {
//add only if the value is number
if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
    sum += parseFloat(this.value);
}
});
//.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
$('input.dailycollectionstotal').val(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

I created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tmac187/pQ8WD/

I put an alert after calculateTotal(); and the alert popped up. Not sure why it's not working. jslint didn't show anything of note that I could see. I tried firebug but I'm still fairly new to it so not 100% sure what I'm looking for there...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One minor bug

```
//Remove Invoice Line
$(document).on('click', 'input.removeItem', function () { 
    var currentTable = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    calculateTableSum(currentTable);
    calculateTotal();
});

....

function calculateSum() {
    var currentTable = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
    calculateTableSum(currentTable);
}

function calculateTableSum(currentTable) {
    var sum = 0;
    $('#' + currentTable + ' input.amtcollected').each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $('#' + currentTable + ' input.sumamtcollected').val(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pQ8WD/1/)

`var currentTable = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');` in `calculateSum` is buggy when you are calling from `remove` handler since then `this` points to the `window` object rather than the removed item.